# How to vertically center inline elements in CSS

Tags: html, css, alignment, vertical-alignment

This may seem like a silly question, but I am not getting the expected results from `vertical-align`.  So…

1. Does `vertical-align:center` center the *child items* of the item that has this property, or does it center *the item itself* that has this property, within its parent?
2. To me, “center” means the distances between the item’s top margin and the container’s top padding, and the item’s bottom margin and the container’s bottom padding are the same.  This doesn’t seem to always be the case.  Is the “bottom” of an inline element the baseline of the text?

Thanks!

Comment: Not vertical-align:center, It is vertical-align:middle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp

According to that, vertical-align:middle make the item itself in middle according to the parent.

Comment: A really useful note about this: The "middle" is **not based on the height of the parent** - it is based on the _**height of the tallest sibling**_